# Action of a cyclic group on $F_2^n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Let $F_2=\{0,1\}$ and consider a cyclic group of order $n$ acting on $F_2^n$ by cyclically exchanging the canonical basis vectors. Which are the orbits of such an action?

Let us see it for $n=4$. The cyclic group $G$ of order $4$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}:=\{[0],[1],[2],[3]\}$. If I take the canonical basis vectors of $F_2^4$, I have $(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)$ as canonical basis. Now, let $(1,1,0,0)=(1,0,0,0)+(0,1,0,0)$. The action of $G$ on $(1,1,0,0)$ is as follows:

$$
0 \cdot (1,1,0,0)=(1,1,0,0)
$$

$$
1 \cdot (1,1,0,0)=(0,1,0,0)+(0,0,1,0)=(0,1,1,0)
$$

and so on?

Comment: If it is "cyclically permuting coordinates", then $1$ should send $(1,1,0,0)$ to $(0,1,1,0)$. And $(0,1,0,0)+(0,0,1,0)$ is not $(0,0,1,0)$.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, there is a misprint.

Comment: I mean, the answer is "strings of 0s and 1s, where two strings are considered equal if they are rotations of each other".  They are also sometimes called "necklaces": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)